# How to easy handle null when load csv in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

I know I cloud use code like below

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jexp/d788e117129c3730a042/raw/c5f98f269b4a219ebb88bd3eb83d331f439a8201/people.csv"
  AS line
WITH line

WHERE line.PersonName IS NOT NULL

RETURN line.PersonName, coalesce(line.Company,"None")
```

but in my situation there are many attribute of line is null.Could I iterate the line(map structure) in neo4j? May be like this `for k,v in line`.

Comment: If you assign null to a property it will not be created

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by MicTech, `COALESCE` here will do the job.

For your question, you can iterate over k,v's of the line map :

```
LOAD CSV 
WITH HEADERS FROM "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ikwattro/29d133f8b2a8f022f5c9/raw/adbab9762ff0a15df18b49c9765ba3377d0e3ece/mockdata.csv" AS line 
WITH line
UNWIND keys(line) as k
RETURN k, line[k] as v
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible in 2.3

`WHERE none(k in keys(line) WHERE line[key] IS NULL)`

In 2.2.x I think the only way to iterate is to use the `LOAD CSV FROM ... AS line` syntax which returns the line as collection of strings. But then you lose access via the keys.

```
LOAD CSV FROM ... AS line 
WHERE NONE(value in line WHERE values IS null)
...
```

Comment: nice stuff for the where none !

Answer (score 1):

instead in your statement of

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "..."
WITH line
WHERE ...
RETURN ...
```

you can use

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "..."
WITH line skip 200 limit 100
WHERE ...
RETURN ...
```

by using proper values for 200 and 100 in the above example you can "browse". Browsing could be achieved by e.g. a shell script that issues this statement in a for loop.